# SQL delete multiple criteria duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a table with duplicate records in all but one field (col4 for ex).  I just need to delete the duplicate entries where the t1.col4 field is blank.

```
ID  Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
1   Joe     1      2      Yes
2   Sue     1      2      
3   Joe     2      3      
4   Joe     1      2
```

Goal: Delete only ID 4

I have tried both the inner join (I don't think msaccess allows this) and WHERE EXISTS/IN techniques with errors.

Exists technique deletes all records where t1.col4 is null (not just ones matched in subquery):

```
DELETE t1.*
  FROM t1
  WHERE Exists (
    SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
      FROM t1
      Group by t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
      HAVING Count(*) > 1
    )
    AND t1.col4 Is Null;
```

I've tried multiple iterations of the Inner Join technique but everything I've read here suggests it is not supported in Access. Happy to post what I've tried if it helps.  I've also tried writing the subquery to a temptable and then trying to delete records matched by the inner join.

Comment: Add some input data (not an image!) and an expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE t1
  FROM t1
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
                FROM t1 as tt1
                WHERE t1.col1 = tt1.col1 AND t1.col2 = tt1.col2 AND t1.col3 = tt1.col3 AND t1.id <> tt1.id
               ) AND
        t1.col4 Is Null;
```

Comment: Close...   Looks like you're all set up but forgot the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: Wow...works perfectly so far with my tests even without the group by.  You guys are too smart for me.  Is there somewhere I can read about why/when a correlated subquery is required?

Comment: also interesting is why a table alias works in the subquery but not in the parent.